# JPQL Create new Object In Select Statement - avoid or embrace?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, jpql

I've learnt recently that it is possible to create new Objects in `JPQL` statements as follows:

```
select new Family(mother, mate, offspr)
from DomesticCat as mother
    join mother.mate as mate
    left join mother.kittens as offspr
```

Is this something to be avoided or rather to embrace? When is usage of this feature justified in the light of good practices?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

**Don't avoid it**, the SELECT NEW is there because there are perfectly valid use cases for it as reminded in the *§10.2.7.2. JPQL Constructor Expressions in the SELECT Clause* of the [EJB 3.0 JPA Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor):

> A constructor may be used in the
>   SELECT list to return one or more Java
>   instances. The specified class is not
>   required to be an entity or to be
>   mapped to the database. **The
>   constructor name must be fully
>   qualified.**
>
> If an entity class name is specified
>   in the SELECT NEW clause, the
>   resulting entity instances are in the
>   new state.
>
> ```
> SELECT NEW com.acme.example.CustomerDetails(c.id, c.status, o.count)
> FROM Customer c JOIN c.orders o
> WHERE o.count > 100
> ```

In short, use the SELECT NEW when you don't want to retrieve a full entity or a full graph of objects in a type safe way (as opposed to an `Object[]`). Whether you map the result of a query in an entity class or a non mapped class will depend on your select. A typical example would be a list screen (where you might not want all the details).

In other words, don't use it everywhere but don't forbid its use (few things are only black or white).

Comment: I want to made the same thing but in my query I have some join fetch and jpa complains : `query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list`. Sad...

Comment: Please edit your answer and make "The constructor name must be fully qualified" bold.. it is very important and a common source of errors.

Comment: The answer is totally right, but the linked document doesn't match the answer. It should be http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/index.html

Comment: If you're using a `static` nested class, use `$`, e.g. `SELECT NEW org.soluvas.sanad.core.QuranManager$QuranChapterSummary(c.chapterNum, c.name, c.verseCount) FROM QuranChapter c`

Comment: @DominikDorn could you please clarify why full constructor name so important? What mistakes did you have in mind?

Comment: @Woland because the query is passed to hibernate/jpa as a string and JPA does not know which class is meant in the query. you could have 10 CustomerDetails classes in your project.. this is how you tell hibernate/jpa which one to use.

Comment: In new object there are lot of parameters due to join queries result. Can we reduce those no of parameters in constructor ?

Answer (score 32):

You often use this sort of query when you want to retrieve a **Data Transfer Object**. Maybe a report can be a good place to use it. If you just want to retrieve a single domain object (like *from Family* instead), so there is no reason to use it.

Comment: Good point, but do you think that Repository should return DTOs and not entities? I am converting the objects in Service layer normally, in Repository is not too early?

Answer (score 7):

An Object created with new does not have to be a DTO, i.e. an Object which will be exported by the Business layer. It can also be a POJO Domain Object, i.e. an Object used internally by the Business layer.

The reason to use this kind of POJOs as a partial Object instead of the full JPA Entity is performance in specific kinds of JOINS. A great resource which explains this is: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/join/hash-join-partial-objects