# How to deal with Object type returned by JPQL query?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I can do this easily with JPQL that only returns data from one table.

```
SELECT m1 FROM MasatosanTest m1
```

That means one data type is returned. So I can just store the query result into the List with type specified:

```
List<MasatosanTest> mt = query.getResultList();
```

**code snippet**

```
private static final String JPQL_TEST = "SELECT m1 FROM MasatosanTest m1;

    @Path("innerJoin")
        @GET
        @Produces("application/json")
        public List<MasatosanTest> getJoinedResult() {
            System.out.println("getJoinedResult called");
            EntityManager em = null;
            List<MasatosanTest> mt = null;

            try {
                em = EmProvider.getDefaultManager();
                Query query = em.createQuery(JPQL_TEST);
                mt = query.getResultList();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("MasatosanTestResource.java - getJoinedResult ERROR: " + e);
            }
            finally {
                if(em != null) {
                    em.close();
                }
            }
            return mt;
        }
```

Now, if I try JPQL that involves 2 tables....

**query**

```
SELECT m1, m2 FROM Masatosan m1, Masatosan2 m2;

List<Masatosan> result = query.getResultList();
```

This does not cause immediate error however actually Object type is being returned instead of particular type such as `Masatosan` or `Masatosan2`

So when I iterate, it cause CASTException,

```
for(Masatosan item : result) { .... }
```

What is the good way to deal with this scenario?

**UPDATE**

If I system print the variable "`result`" it spits:

```
return object ==========>
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@1540f1e, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1ac7e54, [Ljava.lang.Object;@199cd0a, 
[Ljava.lang.Object;@6487d7, [Ljava.lang.Object;@125755, [Ljava.lang.Object;@239ff3, 
[Ljava.lang.Object;@da2335, [Ljava.lang.Object;@13da77b, [Ljava.lang.Object;@bea4e1, 
[Ljava.lang.Object;@3add4b, [Ljava.lang.Object;@968e06, [Ljava.lang.Object;@4642c8, 
[Ljava.lang.Object;@ca81a4, [Ljava.lang.Object;@105510f, [Ljava.lang.Object;@cde78, 
[Ljava.lang.Object;@e1b60e, [Ljava.lang.Object;@776306, [Ljava.lang.Object;@6275c, 
[Ljava.lang.Object;@21035, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1762346, [Ljava.lang.Object;@105ea3d, 
[Ljava.lang.Object;@15564f6, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1577817, [Ljava.lang.Object;@18d30be, 
[Ljava.lang.Object;@7b235c, [Ljava.lang.Object;@4e83d4, [Ljava.lang.Object;@b0f862]
```

First, I thought i was in array but **that [ bracket inside the first one seems to be just a part of String???**

To test:

```
 for(Object items : result) {
            System.out.println("-------------------" + items);
            System.out.println(items.toString());
            return null;
        }
```

This will output:

```
 -------------------[Ljava.lang.Object;@c723e8
[Ljava.lang.Object;@c723e8
```

So the square bracket next to "L" does not represent array.

This means the query result is actually store in `List<Object>` which consists of objects of 2 types (i.e. M`asatosan Object` and `Masatotan2` Object)

And ClassCastException :( I'm confused, it should be castable)

```
 int count = 0;
        for(Object items : mt) {
            System.out.println("-------------- " + count + " --------------" + items);
            count ++;
            Masatosan woot = (Masatosan) items;
            System.out.println(woot.getUsername());
        }

java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to local.test.entity.Masatosan
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That possibly returns a `List<Object[]>`. The message of the `ClassCastException` will have the exact type. In case I'm correct:

```
for (Object[] items : result) {
    Masatosan m1 = (Masatosan) items[0];
    Masatosan m2 = (Masatosan) items[1];
}
```

To quote [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14571_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html)

> When multiple select_expressions are used in the SELECT clause, the result of the query is of type Object[], and the elements in this result correspond in order to the order of their specification in the SELECT clause

Comment: Ahh got it, no wonder it won't cast, didn't think about it inside of array, thanks for the doc link and help!

Comment: Actually i'm not seeing array if I'm not mistaken.. Will update.

Comment: Ok... I've confirmed that you were correct. I was running faulty test :p    I was doing List<Object> instead of using List<Object[]> so my test was returning invalid output.

Comment: +1 about to ask the same question.  Nice concise clear answer, thanks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2355728/286532 for using SELECT NEW to feed the results into a class constructor