# executing case expressions in jpql

Tags: java, jpql

I'm learning JPA and doing some hands one with JPQL. I am having trouble in CASE expressions. 
For example, this query,

```
Query caseQuery = em
            .createQuery("SELECT t , CASE WHEN t.salary = 20000 THEN '20k' WHEN t.salary = 40000 THEN '40k' ELSE 'No salary' END FROM Teacher t");
```

and executing it using

```
List<Teacher> teachers = (List<Teacher>) caseQuery.getResultList();
```

but whenever I try to print the results out, I'm getting `ClassCastException` that `Object` cannot be converted to `Teacher`

I've tried using `TypedQuery` for `Teacher` but it didn't work. Could you experts please throw some light on executing this `CASE` statements in JPQL?

Comment: I think that's case was introduced in JPA 2.0 - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427447/is-there-such-thing-case-expression-in-jpql

Comment: @Leo I've already seen that question, that explains how to write CASE expressions and even books and official docs explain that. I'm having trouble in executing CASE query and getting results.

Comment: I see. In your case, you're retrieving more than a Teacher object, so I think you have to return something else than a Teacher object in your query

Comment: Maybe you could use something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355728/jpql-create-new-object-in-select-statement-avoid-or-embrace

Comment: @Leo, well I'm selecting only Teacher entities but the introduction of CASE expression causes problems, this is where I'm not getting how it works.

Comment: You are selecting a `Teacher` and a `String`, so your result is going to be `List<Object[]>` not `List<Teacher>`. Each `Object[]` will have two elements: the first being a `Teacher`, the second being the result of the case statement.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is due to multiple select expressions in your query and not due to CASE Expression ,I believe with multiple select expressions the result will be Object[] rather than translated to the Entity. Some references [JPA Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html#bnbvy) ;[JPQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_resulttype). A related query already in [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507686/how-to-deal-with-object-type-returned-by-jpql-query).

Answer (score 0):

You should modify

```
List<Teacher> teachers = (List<Teacher>) caseQuery.getResultList();
```

to

```
List<Object[]> teachers = (List<Object[]>) caseQuery.getResultList();
```

where `Object[]` will be an array of `Teacher`& `String`

For `TypedQuery` also similar change should work.