# cast is not working from list<>

Tags: java, jpa

Why does this cast fail? Since results for me is a List of Average. But apparently some magic is needed since java thinks it's an Object.

When working further with this it seems like the q.getResultList() call will give me a raw list of object which seems strange to me, since it's a TypedQuery.

```
TypedQuery<Average> q = em.createQuery("select p.id, p.lastName, p.firstName, c.name, s.serieDate, st.serie_type, st.serie_type_info, count(s.player.id), sum(s.result), avg(s.result) from Serie s, Player p, Club c, SerieType st " +
        " where p.id = s.player.id" +
        " and c.id = s.club.id " +
        " and st.id = s.serieType.id " +
        " and c.name like '%" + clubName + "%'" +
        " and st.serie_type like '%" + serieType.getSerie_type() + "%'" +
        " and st.serie_type_info like '%" + serieType.getSerie_type_info() + "%'" +
        " and s.serieDate > :startDate" +
        " and s.serieDate < :endDate" +
        " group by p.id, p.lastName, p.firstName, c.name, s.serieDate, st.serie_type, st.serie_type_info", Average.class);
        q.setParameter("startDate", calendarBean.getDate1());
        q.setParameter("endDate", calendarBean.getDate2());
```

Here is the call

```
List<Average> resultList = q.getResultList();
List<Average> withAverages = CalculateAveragesClub(resultList);

private List CalculateAveragesClub(List<Average> results)   {
        for (Average average : results) { //error in this cast
}
```

---

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/BowlingFacelets] threw exception [[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.jk.hcp.Average] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.jk.hcp.Average
    at com.jk.hcp.ServiceSeries.CalculateAveragesClub(ServiceSeries.java:508)
```

Comment: First of all check what you put inside method as parameter, and better to post more code.

Comment: Where do you call `CalculateAveragesClub` from and what is the type of that input parameter?

Comment: Where exactly is that exception thrown?
Try setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code.

Comment: Add code snap where you call the `CalculateAveragesClub` method!

Comment: Added more info in the question.

Answer (score 1):

A little more searching and I would have found

[JPQL Create new Object In Select Statement - avoid or embrace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355728/jpql-create-new-object-in-select-statement-avoid-or-embrace)

credits to Xavi for leading me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

With the code and the error you posted, it looks like that method is expecting a `List<Average>`, but the elements in the `List` are `Object[]` actually (*at least* one of them is).

Here's an [**Ideone sample**](http://ideone.com/xkZW30) reproducing the problem with the `String` class instead of `Average`.

Make sure to have `Average` objects in the `List`.

Type safety is not enforced on the code calling that method because of `q.getResultList()` returning a raw `List` (without generic type).

```
List<Average> resultList = q.getResultList();
```

**EDIT**
According to the edit, it looks like the `List` is returned by a JPA/Hibernate `Query`. If it is an Hibernate `SQLQuery` along the lines of `SELECT * from average_table`, make sure to call [`addEntity()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/SQLQuery.html#addEntity%28java.lang.Class%29) (in any of its convenient flavors) on the `SQLQuery` so that it returns `Average` objects instead of Object arrays with all the columns in the query (or use HQL/Criteria if suitable).

```
q.addEntity(Average.class);
List<Average> resultList = q.getResultList();
```

You might find [Chapter 16 - Native SQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html) of the Hibernate Reference useful, specially [16.1.2. Entity queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13696).

Comment: Seems to refer to jboss entities. It's a Derby database and eclipselink is used for JPA.

Comment: @user2130951 Not familiar with `TypedQuery`, but it seems JPA won't know how to convert that collection of selected properties to an `Average` instance automagically. Is there an `Average` constructor using those fields? If there is so, you could try `SELECT new Average(p.id, ...) FROM ...`

Comment: @user2103951 Glad you've solved it. Would you mind posting and accepting an answer with the details so that future visitors of the question can find a suitable accepted answer? Remember upvoting answers that were helpful and accepting the best answer is a great way of contributing to the site and improving its quality, while giving back :-)

Comment: I am not sure that this is anything to post. The solution seems really backwards to me and not at all something I would recommend unless there is absolutely no other way to do it. Since I have to send in an Object[] and cast everything while creating an Average object.