# Selecting from Multiple Tables in Spring JPA with Pageable and Sorting

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I saw the [Selecting from Multiple Tables in Spring Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638465/selecting-from-multiple-tables-in-spring-data) already had the solution for multiple tables.
I would like to know if it is possible to write custom query that has tables with pageable and sorting feature at the same time in Spring JPA/DATA.

```
SELECT s.service_id, s.name, us.rating_id 
FROM services s, 
   ratings r, 
   user_services us
where 
   us.service_id = s.service_id and
   us.rating_id = r.rating_id and
   us.user_id= ?
;
```

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: Show your model...

Comment: this is a general question. why need model?

Comment: to let us help you. query and query method are depend on your model...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorting feature is under question, but pagination is possible to use.

Assume that we have:

```
@Entity
public class Service {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    //...
}

@Entity
public class UserService {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne        
    User user;

    @ManyToOne        
    Service service;   

    @ManyToOne        
    Rating rating;   

    //...
}
```

Then we create a projection:

```
public interface ServiceRating {
    Long getServiceId();
    String getServiceName();
    Long getRatingId();
}
```

And then create a query method supported pagination:

```
public interface UserServiceRepo extends CrudRepository<UserService, Long> {
    @Query("select s.id as serviceId, s.name as serviceName, us.rating.id as ratingId from UserService us join us.service s where us.user.id = ?1")
    Page<ServiceRating> getServiceRating(Long userId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

(Since this query does not contain grouping it's not necessary to use an additional `countQuery` (see the parameter of `@Query`)).

Test:

```
Page<ServiceRating> pages = userServiceRepo.getServiceRating(1L, new PageRequest(0, 10));
assertThat(pages.getContent()).hasSize(10));
```

**UPDATE**

Sorting also working perfectly.
Just create a Sort object, specify direction and filed name (from the projection):

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "serviceName");
userServiceRepo.getServiceRating(1L, new PageRequest(0, 10, sort));
```

Comment: Thank you @Cepr0!

Comment: @linc01n 'Thank you' is equal to 'accepting/upvoting' the answer here. Please don't forget to do it...

Comment: Hi, I met a problem: When I create a projection interface and try to run the application, An error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type ....