# JpaPagingItemReader not creating entity objects

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-batch

I'm using `spring-batch` and the `JpaPagingItemReader<T>` to read a DB to `@Entity`.
The entity is correctly specified as type argument `T`.

Problem: The result set that is returned is not of type `T`, but an array of objects: `Object[]`. Each object in that array itself is an `Object[]` array having the following content: `[firstname, lastname, date]`.

So, the database columns are somehow written as String array, and the entities are returned obviously as `String[]` array.

The reason for this is my query:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, min(date) FROM mytable GROUP BY firstname, lastname;
```

So the reader maps to a string array. How can I have a mapping to my `@Entity`, maybe only filled with the fields requested in the select?

My reader definition:

```
JpaPagingItemReader<MyEntity> reader = new JpaPagingItemReader<>();
reader.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
reader.setQueryString(QUERY);

@Entity
public class MyEntity {
   private String firstname, lastname;
   private Date date;

   public MyEntity(String firstname, String lastname, Date date) {
       this.firstname = firstname;
       this.lastname = lastname;
       this.date = date;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your bean reader definition?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add my query, which is probably the reason...

Comment: Isn't this using JPQL with JpaPagingItemReader? Added the reader definition above. From the docs: `It executes the JPQL {@link #setQueryString(String)} to retrieve requested
* data.`

Comment: I think if you want to keep your query as it is but you want to return an object, you will have to create a POJO whose constructor accepts (String, String, Date) (but it wont be your Entity).

Comment: Hm ok that's not what I want. How could I rewrite the query so that it returns the entity?

Comment: @ccheneson It can be an entity as long as the constructor matches it will work.

Comment: I added my entity above, which has a constructor with the params matching the returned columns. Though the automatic mapping does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT m FROM mytable m GROUP BY m.firstname, m.lastname;
```

This should return your entity

Here is an example of a declarative way of defining your reader:

```
<beans:bean id="myreader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader">
    <beans:property name="queryString"
        value="SELECT m FROM mytable m GROUP BY m.firstname, m.lastname" />
    <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</beans:bean>
```

**Edit**:

From M.Deinum comment, you should be able to use this:

```
SELECT new com.myproject.model.MyEntity(firstname, lastname, min(date)) FROM mytable GROUP BY firstname, lastname
```

Comment: Error: `Column m.* must occur in GROUP-BY clause or used in an aggregate function` (free translation from the native language output.

Comment: Great! The new operator works indeed. Is this the correct way to do things?

Comment: If you want to return a subset of your entity yes. But since you just have 3 attributes in your entity it is fine. If you have 20 attributes in your entity and you need to return only a few, you d better go with a new POJO - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355728/jpql-create-new-object-in-select-statement-avoid-or-embrace