# JPA avoid List<Obect[]> when selecting multiple entites

Tags: jpa, mapping, multi-select, pojo

In my repository I have a query that looks like this:

```
 @Query("select us,ul FROM UserScore us LEFT JOIN us.userLike ul WHERE us.param1=:param1 and ul.param2=:param2)
    public List<Object[]> getTest(@Param("param1") Integer param1, @Param("param2") Integer param2);
```

Is there a way to avoid  returning List  and instead returning something like this List ?

```
@Entity
public UserScoreUserLike {
     private UserScore userScore;
     private UserLike userLike
[getters setters]
}
```

In a way, making JPA mapped the result of the multi select with my custom Entity/POJO?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "select new" notation is your friend, where you're selecting the creation of a wrapper object. So your JPA query would look something like

```
select new UserScoreUserLike(us, ul) from UserScore ...
```

Note that your wrapper object doesn't have to be (and maybe shouldn't be) and entity object.

See this other StackOverflow answer: [JPQL Create new Object In Select Statement - avoid or embrace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355728/jpql-create-new-object-in-select-statement-avoid-or-embrace)

Comment: Glad to help! Yeah, it's very handy.