# java.sql.SQLException: Column 'max_grade' not Found where sql query do not contain 'max_grade'

Tags: java, mysql

My problem is I try to get values from 3 table joining. My mysql query is as follows. It works properly without any errors in sql console. But give errors when run using Java:

```
StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder();
queryString.append("SELECT cs.id, MIN( s.grade_level_val ) as minGrade, MAX( s.grade_level_val ) as maxGrade FROM class_section cs ")
           .append("LEFT JOIN enrollment e ON e.class_section_id = cs.id ")
           .append("LEFT JOIN student s ON s.id = e.student_id ")
           .append("WHERE cs.id = :classSectionId");

TypedQuery<ClassSectionVO> query = (TypedQuery<ClassSectionVO>) entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString.toString(), ClassSectionVO.class);
query.setParameter("classSectionId", classSectionId);

List<ClassSectionVO> result = query.getResultList();
```

And here is `ClassSectionVO`:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class ClassSectionVO implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "minGrade")
    private Short minGrade;

    @Column(name = "maxGrade")
    private Short maxGrade;

    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Short getMinGrade()
    {
        return minGrade;
    }

    public void setMinGrade(Short minGrade)
    {
        this.minGrade = minGrade;
    }

    public Short getMaxGrade()
    {
        return maxGrade;
    }

    public void setMaxGrade(Short maxGrade)
    {
        this.maxGrade = maxGrade;
    }
}
```

There is no column `max_grade` in the query but its gives me the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException :column 'max_grade' not found.
```

Comment: The query language used in JPA is not the same as used in MySQL. You need to rewrite your query.

Comment: Could you please give me an example for that

Comment: @RogerGustavsson Not when writing a native query as it is done here.

Comment: @UweAllner Oops. My bad. But some JPA/JPQL stuff seems to have crept through. The change of `maxGrade` to `max_grade`.

Comment: Maybe look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355728/jpql-create-new-object-in-select-statement-avoid-or-embrace and http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-basics/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JPA, in your POJOs you use camelCase like maxGrade but JPA translates that to lowercase with underscores for the actual columns in the database so maxGrade would correspond to a DB column called max_grade so the actual query will look for max_grade in the database and not maxGrade. This is convention and you can override it but its better to have database columns as lowercase with underscores if you are joining words and camelCase in code.

Answer (score 2):

If your [`Configuration`](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#setNamingStrategy(org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy)) object sets an [`ImprovedNamingStrategy`](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html), then camelCase names get converted to snake_case.

If you don't want snake_case, then either don't set the naming strategy or else set it to the [`DefaultNamingStrategy`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/DefaultNamingStrategy.html).

Comment: Or is this a case where `minGrade` and `maxGrade` should be put inside back-ticks? Since they are aliases. Will they then not be touched by JPA or will that happen anyway?

Comment: @RogerGustavsson: I believe it's the other way around—the entity manager is expecting snake_case in the resultset but is finding camelCase, so changing the query (ostensibly to ensure camelCase results when they're already there) won't achieve anything.  Of course, one could change the query to use snake_case if so desired.

Comment: @eggyyal: Maybe I'm still missing something, but `maxGrade` is used to name a result column. The query never tries to read from a column `maxGrade` nor `max_grade`, so why would `maxGrade` be translated to `max_grade`? The error message suggests it has been.

Comment: @RogerGustavsson: The entity is declared with `@Column(name="maxGrade")`, which `ImprovedNamingStrategy` converts to `max_grade`.  The resultset doesn't contain a column named `max_grade`, so the entity manager complains `column 'max_grade' not found`.

Comment: See. I knew I was missing something. I'll be quiet now.

Comment: Grade job guys I got the answer, reason was same camelCase Issue. I fixed it it working properly

Answer (score 1):

For the future, after hours of searching and searching this saved me :
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl