# JPQL Query with calculated value?

Tags: jpql

I want to use a calculated value in the WHERE clause and in an ORDER BY expression. In plain sql it would look like

```
SELECT some, colums, (some arbitrary math) AS calc_value FROM table WHERE calc_value <= ? ORDER BY calc_value
```

If I try in JPQL

```
entitymanager.createQuery("SELECT e, (some arbitrary math) AS calc_value FROM Entity e WHERE calc_value <= :param ORDER BY calc_value", Entity.class);
```

it fails. Obviously, because the return of the query is the tuple of Entity and calc_value (i.e. Double).

Is there a way of getting this into one query, using strong typed return values (i.e. Entity.class, as the calculated value doesn't matter).

Comment: Try creating a DTO and return it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355728/jpql-create-new-object-in-select-statement-avoid-or-embrace

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem and didn't resolve the problem to fetch it into the correct object:

- Tried all constructor combinations for the object - no luck.
- tried Tuple.class - no luck.

Finally I used this approach and then fetched oject[0] into my real Java-Object:

```
TypedQuery<Object[]> q = em.createQuery("select v, (2 * 4) as temp from MyObject v order by temp", Object[].class);
List<Object[]> results = q.getResultList();

for (Object[] o : results) 
  MyObject mo = (MyObject) o[0];
```