# HQL left join with condition

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join, hql

This may seem basic but it's late and I'm having trouble with the following.

```
class Group {

  @Id
  String id;
}

class Participation {

  @Id
  String id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID")
  Group group;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
  User user;
}

class User {

  @Id
  String id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  Set<Participation> participations;
}
```

[Class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahnTE.png)

So

Participation -->1 Group

and User 1<-->N Participation

How can I retrieve all Groups with, for a given User, the associated Participation (or null is there is none)? I've been playing with join fetches but to no avail so far...

Many thanks,

CN

PS. I can do this in SQL thus :

```
select g.d, p.id 
from group as g 
left join participation as p 
on p.group_id = g.id and p.user_id = 2;
```

Comment: edit: Added diagram and better sql solution...

Answer (score 7):

(Probably some typo in the HQL itself but the idea should be correct)

What you are asking, based on your SQL and description, is find out all `Participation` (and its corresponding `Group`) based on `User`, which is simply

```
select p.id, p.group.id from Participation p where p.user.id = :userId
```

To make it better, you should fetch the entities instead:

```
from Participation p left join fetch p.group where p.user.id = :userId
```

---

There were some confusions in understanding what you were trying to do:
You want all groups (regardless of condition).  And, for a given user, you want to find all groups and participations that user is involved.

Though it should be possible using Right-outer-join:

```
select g, p from Participation p 
    right outer join p.group g 
    where p.user.id=:userId
```

Or, in later version of Hibernate (>= 5.1 ?), it allow explicit join (haven't tried before, you may give it a try) (Replace `with` with `on` if you are using JPQL):

```
select g, p from Group g
    left outer join Participation p 
        with p.group = g
    left outer join p.user u
    where u.id = :userId
```

Or you may use other techniques such as subquery etc.  However I would rather separate them into simpler queries in your case and do a simple aggregation in your code.

The basic idea is to have

1. Query for all groups: `from Groups`
2. Query for all participations for a user: `from Participation p join fetch p.group where p.user.id=:userId`

Then you can aggregate them easily to the form you want, e.g. `Map<Group, List<Participation>>`, or even more meaningful value object.

The benefit is the data access query is simpler and more reusable (esp if you are wrapping them in DAO/Repository finder method).  One more round trip to DB shouldn't cause any obvious performance impact here.

Comment: Thanks, except that this way I don't get the Groups without a Participation for the specified User.

Comment: I don't have dbms on hand but doing a left join as your example with user id should still only give you group with participant isn't it? And you asked for "for a given user, the given participation" which giving you participation with no user is contradict with what you asked for. Anyway, have a try for `from Participation p left join p.user u where u.id =:userid or u is null`

Comment: Agh I guess I misunderstood what you asked. You actually want all groups right? Anyway iirc, HQL do support Right Join, so you can start with Participation right join p.group?

Answer (score -1):

You need to map the `participation` relationship in the `Group` entity. If the relationship between `Participation` and `Group` is 1..N:

```
class Group {
  String id
  List<Participation> participations
}
```

The JPQL can be:

```
SELECT g.id, p.id FROM Group g
JOIN g.participations p
JOIN p.user user
WHERE user.id = :idUser
```

You can receive this information as `List<Object[]>` (`Object[0]` is group id and `Object[1]` is participation id) or use [SELECT NEW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2359214/2387977).

**Without** map the Group/Participation relationship, you can do:

```
SELECT g.id, p.id FROM Group g, Participation p
JOIN p.user user
JOIN p.group groupp
WHERE g.id = groupp.id
AND user.id = :idUser
```

But you can't do a `LEFT JOIN` using this strategy. The query above behaviours like a `JOIN`.

It's normal with Hibernate you map the side of a relationship that you would like to make a query. So, I recommend the first approach, mapping the relationship.

Comment: I'm afraid the relationship between Participation and Group isn't 1:1 (I've added a diagram to the original question).

Comment: @ChambreNoire, no problem! I edited my question, but works in the same way

Comment: No way of doing it without adding the Group>Participation association?

Comment: Theta join is something I would rather avoid (esp new version of hibernate allow arbitrary "on" clause for joins now). And the relationship in entities should be good enough to write meaningful HQL

Comment: @AdrianShum, What join are you talking? He not provide the version of Hibernate too.

Comment: Theta style join means : `FROM Group g, Participation p ... WHERE g.id = groupp.id ...` . There are drawbacks using this: 1. it simply cannot do what OP is asking for (outer joins) 2. It is difficult to read.